# Issue in reports and dashboards view

Tags: reporting

i have 2 managers named A and B.
Under A, teammates X,Y and Z are assigned.
Under B teammates P,Q and R are assigned.
We have built a report forn Manager can view teammate's cases based on the filter 'My Role-based Team's cases'.
But A  can able to see cases of X,Y,Z and P,Q,R also..
How to restrict the manager A to see only cases of X,Y and Z only.. not P,Q and R